# Does re.match(r'.*', string) have a limit?

Tags: python, regex

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import re

my_string = 'This is the string to test.  It has several Capitalized words.  My name is Robert, and I am learning pYthon.'
result = re.match(r'.*', my_string)
result.group(0)

print(result)
```

Forgive me for any issues I create posting this. I am a total noob. I am trying to figure out why it is that when I run the above code, 
I get the follow results and not the full string.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 108), match='This is the string to test.  It has several Capit>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing result, not result.group(0). Just do

```
print(result.group(0))
```

and you will see the whole string.

Comment: Thank You!!! You wouldn't believe my thought process on trying to figure this out!

Comment: These things happen :) If your question was resolved, please, mark the answer as accepted so it gets closure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk of printing a regex match object. If you look in the `span` attribute of the object, the match goes from char 0 to the last char of your string (108), and if you print `result[0]` as @sergio stated, you get the whole string